# WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.mosquitto.org:8080/mqtt' failed

Tags: websocket, mqtt

There are similar questions on stackoverflow asked on this topic, and I have read through them all but still can't see what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to connect with (for now) the mosquitto test broker, using websockets.
As far as I can see, I have the correct host and port setup.

I created file websockets-4.htm (which I have pasted at the bottom of this post), and when I open it, I get the following feedback:

```
connecting to test.mosquitto.org
WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.mosquitto.org:8080/mqtt' failed
  k._doConnect @mqttws31.min.js:36
  k.connect @mqttws31.min.js:31
  I.connect @mqttws31.min.js:65
  MQTTconnect @websockets-4.htm:53
  (anonymous) @websockets-4.htm:61
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Here is the websockets-4.htm file:

(Note: I just added a function to be called on 'client.onFailure', however I am not even sure if this is a valid property)

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>MQTT WebSocket Example</title>
  <style></style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script type = "text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var mqtt;
    
    host = "test.mosquitto.org"
    port = 8080;
    clientId = "myclientid111_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10)
    
// Create a client instance
    var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host, Number(port), clientId);
    
// set callback handlers
    client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
    client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
    client.onFailure = onFailedConnection;
    
// called when the client connects
    function onConnect() {
      console.log("onConnect");
      message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("topic1");
      message.destinationName = "topic1";
      client.send(message);
    }
    
// called when the client loses its connection
    function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
      if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
        console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
      }
    }
    
    function onFailedConnection(responseObject) {
      if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
        console.log("onFailedConnection:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
      }
    }
    
// called when a message arrives
    function onMessageArrived(message) {
      console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
    }
    
    
    function MQTTconnect() {
      console.log("connecting to " + host);
// connect the client
//client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});
client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect, cleanSession:true, useSSL:false, keepAliveInterval:10}); // line 53
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Main Body</h1>
  <script>
MQTTconnect();  // line 61
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me (firefox) - the message is published and `onConnect` logged to the console. One thought - you are not accessing this page over https are you?

Comment: I just tried it in Microsoft Edge, and it works! But not in Chrome.

Comment: The script is on my hard drive, so I just copy the URL (C:/myfolder/websockets-4.htm).

Comment: Looks like its the chrome security model (adding an `onFailure` callback would give you the relevant error - AMQJS0007E). Using a secure connection (port 8081 + `useSSL: true`) works fine for me. Note that you are using an old version of the library, I'd suggest upgrading to 1.1.0 (but note you need to change `Paho.MQTT.` to `Paho.` in your code after changing the library link).